# implement updateable recordsets in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, recordset

What would it take to implement an updateable recordset in c#? Think what is available for Sql CE, but implemented for others like Sql Server. Do the recordset classes basically implement 99% of this and would just need some tinkering to get it added, or would this be a big undertaking? Perhaps using some code from Mono and extending it?

Just fyi, one of the early betas of .net 1.1 (if I have my versions correct) actually did implement this, but was later removed due to fear of abuse. Valid concern, but it sure would be handy in certain scenarios.

Comment: Can you show (f.e. with pseudo code) what you mean?

Comment: I am confused by this question also.  AFAIK, updateable recordsets and similar objects are implemented by the client libraries (ADO.net and the client Providers/Drivers) and not in the SQL Server itself.  Any database server that can support transactions and rowversion columns (or "Timestamps" as they used to be called) should be able to support the client libraries in this.

Comment: All we have in ado.net is DataSets and DataReaders. DataReaders are read-only- no updated allowed. Datasets are filled by a query, and then changes to the cached data is sent to the server as a update. It is not a live updateable recordset. A "SqlResultSet" existed in .net 1.1 beta 1, but was later dropped... it supported a scrollable cursor that could update the data over the live connection.

Comment: Doesn't entity framework or similar provide the functionality that you are after?

Comment: EF works disconnected just like datasets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no component available to imitate a *scrollable cursor* that produces and update over a *live connection.* And for some very good reasons that are far from being abused. Not least of which is the fact that it's a **very** poor use of resources on the SQL Server.

Yes, the `SqlDataReader` does provide a *fast-forward* and *read-only* version of a query. Further, the reader only retrieves one row at a time and leaves the connection open the entire time. This allows you to fetch through a very large result set and leave the resources on the SQL Server, and you can do it very quickly.

However, the process of making that a ***live*** feed back to the SQL Server can be simulated pretty easily. And to do this I'm going to recommend [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), for two reasons:

1. It's performance is unrivaled.
2. It's ***very*** light weight and easy to use.

#### Let's keep it simple first...

First let's start with a very simple example, so let's assume I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Field1 FLOAT,
    Field2 VARCHAR(50)
)
```

so now let's get some data from `Foo`, but before we can we need a simple model to put it into:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

and now we just need to get some data:

```
using Dapper;

...

public void ReadFoo()
{
    IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[some connection string]");
    conn.Open();
    var list = conn.Query<Foo>("SELECT * FROM Foo");

    // and now you have a list of Foo objects you can iterate against
}
```

#### Now let's update the data yeah?

Alright, so now that we know how to ***get*** data using Dapper, let's see how we might simulate a **live** stream to the database yeah? So first let's build a base class:

```
public class DapperModelBase
{
    public abstract string PKField { get; }

    protected void OnPropertyValueChanged(string propertyName, object val)
    {
        var sql = string.Format("update {0} set {1} = @value where {2} = @id",
            this.GetType().Name,
            propertyName,
            this.PKField);

        IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[some connection string]");
        conn.Execute(sql, new
            {
                value = val,
                id = this.GetType().GetProperty(this.PKField).GetValue(this, null)
            });
    }
}
```

so now we need to modify the `Foo` class just a tidge:

```
public class Foo
{
    // implement the abstract property
    public string PKField { get { return "ID"; } }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    private float _field1;
    public float Field1
    {
        get { return _field1; }
        set
        {
            _field1 = value;
            OnPropertyValueChanged("Field1", value);
        }
    }

    private string _field2;
    public string Field2
    {
        get { return _field2; }
        set
        {
            _field2 = value;
            OnPropertyValueChanged("Field2", value);
        }
    }
}
```

so now when we update an editable property while iterating we are sending back commands to make this a *live* feed:

```
// and now you have a list of Foo objects you can iterate against
foreach (var foo in list)
{
    ...
    ...
    foo.Field1 = 123f; // sends an update
    ...
    ...
    foo.Field2 = "Hello World!" // sends an update
}
```

now, let's take this one step further, and let's assume that the result set you're getting back is ***massive***, and when I say that I mean ***100's of MB.*** Well, Dapper can handle that too, simply change the line that gets data from:

```
var list = conn.Query<Foo>("SELECT * FROM Foo");
```

to:

```
var list = conn.Query<Foo>("SELECT * FROM Foo", buffered: false);
```

but nothing else changes!

Comment: Excellent writeup, but I actually have very specific technical reasons that I would need a live updateable resultset (aka SqlResultset before it was removed from 1.1 beta...)